# IOS - Google Admob - Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show."

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I spent a day to research this issue, but the result is till nothing. I need your helps, please.

I have an issue about displaying my ADMOB in my iOS app as below :

When I use test ad ID from google :

> bannerUID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
>
> interstitialUID = "ca-app-pub-8501671653071605/2568258533"

They will be displayed perfectly in my test device - iPhone 6s (real device not simulator)

But when I replace test ad ID by my registered ad ID at google.
It's not working with error (both banner and interstitial)

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}

Can anyone help me? please.

Comment: check this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ioXU2nX9W28

Comment: Thank you! I read this topic earlier (before creating my post). But it seems not my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue for a short while. Don't worry, everything in your code will more than likely be spot. In my case, it fixed itself after a few days and started to show ads. Even now I still sometimes get this error when there's no ad to display - which is pretty rare. This is more likely to happen if you've recently signed up to AdMob.

Comment: You are right, guy. It worked!
But sometimes, I still get error, lol. Thanks u again.